# Why do I need SQL Server to install Azure DevOps?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, tfs

I'm currently working on a enterprise that uses TFS 2017, and we pretend to upgrade to Azure DevOps. So far I'm just studying about how to implement this TOOL. I'm new on devops things and I have these following doubts... Why do we need SQL Server to install DevOps Azure? What kind of information are stored in there?

In the server configuration wizard, I have the option to select an existing database to use for the Azure DevOps Server that's being deployed... Can I select the currently database that's used by TFS 2017?

[image]

Comment: *What kind of information are stored in there?* Everything. That's what it uses to persist data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure DevOps Server and Team Foundation Server store just about everything in massive SQL Server databases.

The main server configuration is stored in the `tfs_configuration` database and each project collection is stored in a separate database The default is `tfs_defaultcollection`.

The collection database holds all version controlled files (TFVC and Git), all work items (Product Backlog, Sprints etc), Test Cases and all test run attachments, your Pipelines, Builds and Releases as well as all of the artifacts produced by these pipelines.

These databases can grow considerably.

Whether you can keep your current database server depends on what version you're currently running. SQL Server 2016 SP1+ happens to be supported by both Azure DevOps Server 2020 as well as Team Foundation Server 2017. You could keep using that for the upgraded installation.

But my recommendation would be to install *SQL Server 2019*, you'll get all of the performance and security benefits of the new server, support for the latest Windows Server platform, as well as a support window that matches your new Azure DevOps Server installation.

You can find the SQL Server compatibility matrix for TFS/ADS here:

- [Azure SQL Database and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2020&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#azure-sql-database-and-sql-server)

Answer (score -1):

> What kind of information are stored in there?

Issues, templates, build results, lots of things.

> Can I select the database that's used by TFS 2017?

Yes, that will be upgraded during the installation.

Comment: Untrue. You can use the same database in certain cases.

Comment: @jesse yes, I meant you can use the same database, but it will be upgraded (both configuration and collections), right? For new issue templates, pipeline component definitions, and so on? Or do you mean you can install Azure DevOps on an existing TFS 2017 database in a backwards-compatible way? I've maintained and upgraded from SourceSafe to TFS 2010/2013/2015/2017, then went to different Git hosting services, so my memory might be off.

Comment: They will be upgraded during install.

Answer (score -1):

TFS 2017 was one of the last versions to require a database for the Warehouse, which is a form of replicated data. Reports can be written to pull data from the warehouse, without impacting the user experience. The database is somewhat deprecated now, especially for reporting. Microsoft promotes the use of the API to pull data from the live database. TFS does however still need its "live" database to store all of the data presented to users. These will be work items, discussion comments, project templates, user mappings to AD, amongst other things.

You will need to upgrade your 2017 Schema to conform to the new standard as defined by Azure, which will be taken care of as part of the upgrade.